# « J'espère que vous allez bien ? » Pourquoi le point d'interrogation ?

Tags: questions, ponctuation, correspondance

Dans un email professionnel reçu j'ai lu :

> Bonjour à tous,
>
> « J'espère que vous allez bien **?**»
>
> Je me permet de vous envoyer ce mail afin de vous rappeler certains gestes utiles (...)

Que signifie le point d'interrogation dans *« J'espère que vous allez bien ?»* Est-ce un type de tournure interrogative ? Est-ce une faute de frappe ?

Comment: Just a "feeling" but maybe the email's author used (correctly or not) the question mark to indicate that s/he had a (good) reason to suspect that his/her audience was not happy or in good form (eg, s/he hadn't heard from them in quite a while or they were all out partying the night before & were feeling a bit rough). Although the affirmative statement at issue isn't a clear example of an *interrogation indirecte* or a *proposition interrogative* (as opposed to "Je me demande si vous allez bien.[??]", which, imo, would be a clear example of that style), maybe the author had that in mind.[?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

À l'oral c'est assez courant (tout est relatif évidemment), et il est difficile de dire si c'est réellement une « erreur », étant donné qu'il s'agit surtout de « manière de parler » plutôt que de règle grammaticale. En tout cas c'est quelque chose de très spécifique au français parlé.

Je l'interprète comme cela : on commence à dire « j'espère que vous allez bien », mais réalisant soudain qu'une telle phrase n'attend pas de réponse de l'autre personne, on termine en montant la voix pour que ça ressemble à une question (car ce serait un peu bizarre de simplement dire « j'espère que vous allez bien », qui n'attend pas de réponse, plutôt que de simplement demander à la personne si elle va bien, puisqu'elle est juste là).

On peut imaginer quelque chose de similaire : une personne cherche son chien dans la chambre, et voyant qu'il n'est pas là, dit : « mon chien n'est pas dans la... », mais voyant quelque chose dépasser de sous le lit, qui pourrait être la queue du chien, termine sa phrase en montant la voix : « ... chambre ? », puis va vérifier si c'est le chien. Elle dira alors « Eh bien si, il est là ! » ou « Non en effet, il n'est pas là » selon que c'est bien, ou non, la queue du chien qui dépassait.

Mais ça ne devrait pas être retranscrit dans un mail puisqu'on peut effacer sa phrase avant de l'envoyer.

Answer (score 2):

J'espère que vous allez bien?

Soit:

Traduit une certaine incertitude, une certaine inquiétude même.

Soit:

Est l'équivalent de "Vous allez bien, j'espère?"

Ici, c'est une question indirecte: Je vous demande si vous allez bien.

Comme la forme est plutôt inhabituelle, je pencherais plutôt pour le point d'interrogation-d'incertitude.

Comment: Oui, effectivement, j'ai inversé le "première" et "seconde", merci de me l'avoir fait remarqué. "une typo", oui, 2 lettres inversées. Vous êtes vraiment très attentif! Ne pas hésiter à éditer ma question pour ce genre de fautes.

Answer (score 0):

Ce point d'interrogation découle d'une erreur de compréhension de la langue et d'une erreur d'identification claire de ce qui est ressenti. « J'espère que vous allez bien. » est une affirmation et ne peut en aucun cas être terminé par un point d'interrogation. Le scripteur mélange ses sentiments de nescience à propos de l'état général des personnes auxquelles il/elle s'adresse avec son souci d'exprimer son sentiment d'espoir que ceux-ci ont tout leur bien être. Ce type d'erreur résulte du contexte, lequel cause au   scripteur d'identifier deux états de chose habituels, sans que  dans son esprit il puisse les dissocier, une  ambiguïté qui se traduit, du fait d'une encore incertaine appréhension des pratiques de la langue, en une ambiguïté  dans sa syntaxe.

On pourrait choisir de telles formulations bivalentes comme formules d'ouverture de lettres ou d'entrée en contact vocal, mais je ne trouve pas cette  idée bonne du tout. Elle n'a pas été utilisée jusqu'à présent et il faut espérer qu'elle ne le sera pas à l'avenir.

Comment: il faut espérer qu'elle ne le sera pas à l'avenir...où il faut espérer qu'elle ne soit pas à l'avenir:-)! (Merci pour cette réponse.)

Comment: @Dimitris Il me semble de prime abord que les deux sont possibles, la forme subjonctif étant  cependant, correcte.

Comment: @Dimitris Un ngram pour le verbe « être » semble montrer que le futur serait préféré :  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=esp%C3%A8re+qu%27ils+ne+seront+pas%2Cesp%C3%A8re+qu%27ils+ne+soient+pas&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cesp%C3%A8re%20qu%27ils%20ne%20seront%20pas%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cesp%C3%A8re%20qu'ils%20ne%20seront%20pas%3B%2Cc0

Comment: En fait en language oral on a presque l'inverse: "Comment ca va ?" a de moins en moins valeur de question et de plus en plus valeur d'un simple "Bonjour".

Comment: @LaurentS. Une importante différence dans ce cas d'ambiguïté c'est qu'il est conséquent à un glissement, alors qu'en ce qui concerne le cas de la question, si éventuellement on ne pourrait toujours pas parler d'erreur, il semble difficile d'admettre un glissement, même de la sorte spontanée évoquée dans la réponse de user **[Destal](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40120/17649)**, qui lui-/elle-même dit « Mais ça ne devrait pas être retranscrit dans un mail puisqu'on peut effacer sa phrase avant de l'envoyer. ».

Comment: J'ai downvoté ça en revanche, car je pense que la réponse n'est pas bonne "«J'espère que vous allez bien. » est une affirmation et ne peut en aucun cas être terminé par un point d'interrogation"